# error in creating stored procedure using heidiSQL

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I am trying to write a stored procedure using Heidi sql. I am getting below error. I tested the query and it returns right result, but in Heidi sql, I keep getting below error:

[image]

Below is my query and the screen shot from heidiSQL:

```
DELIMITER //
BEGIN
  SELECT 
  VitalID,
  firstName,
  MiddleName,
  LastName,
  Address,
  Zip,
  City,
  State,
  updatedOn,
  StatusCode
  FROM personalrecord 
END
//

DELIMITER ;
```

[image]

Comment: Put the `DELIMITER //` before `CREATE PROCEDURE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Create procedure statementshould be like

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE index_AllPersonRecordGet()
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC 
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
  SELECT 
  VitalID,
  firstName,
  MiddleName,
  LastName,
  Address,
  Zip,
  City,
  State,
  updatedOn,
  StatusCode
  FROM personalrecord;
END
//

DELIMITER ;
```